Sending data through widgets (as parameters) to a different page... flutter
I am wanting to call class VideoPlayerScreen below from a different file and send through a parameter called link which will be a link to the video displayed here. How do i go about doing this?
I have tried adding a required in the const VideoPlayerScreen({super.key}); line e.g.const VideoPlayerScreen({required this.link, super.key}); and then passing link into here :
_controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(
        link,
      ),
    );

this doesnt seem to work. my end goal is to make this reusable so i can put multiple videos in
any help would be appreicaited.
many thanks.
p.s. below is a copy of the whole video file
i am calling it from inside a center widget in the other file like so :
body: Center(
          child:VideoPlayerScreen()
        )

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';


class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerScreen> createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}


class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  int pressCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4',
      ),
    );

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.play();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void pressed() {
    pressCount = pressCount+1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                );
              } else {
                // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                // loading spinner.
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FilledButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
                // correct icon is shown.
                pressed();
                setState(() {
                  // If the video is playing, pause it.
                  if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                    _controller.pause();
                  } else {
                    // If the video is paused, play it.
                    _controller.play();
                  }
                });
              },
              style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                ),
              ),
              // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
              child: Icon(
                pressCount >= 1 ?
                  _controller.value.isPlaying ?
                    Icons.pause :
                  Icons.play_arrow :
                Icons.pause,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


edit full working code:
tried putting 2 on the screen and there is this massive gap?
Code Picture
about.dart:
import 'package:coffee_card/video_player_widget.dart';

class About extends StatelessWidget {
  const About({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const BackButton(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          "About",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 42,
            fontFamily: "Dancing Script",
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[800],
      ),
      body: const Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: VideoPlayerScreen(
                link: "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: VideoPlayerScreen(
                link: "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

video_player_widget.dart:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;

  const VideoPlayerScreen(
      {required this.link, super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerScreen> createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  int pressCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(
        widget.link,
      ),
    );
    // _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(
    //     widget.link
    // );
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    //
    // // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner while waiting for the
      // VideoPlayerController to finish initializing.
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (_controller.value.isInitialized) {
                // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
                // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                );
              } else {
                // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                // loading spinner.
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FilledButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Duration currentPosition = _controller.value.position;
                    Duration targetPosition =
                        currentPosition - const Duration(seconds: 10);
                    _controller.seekTo(targetPosition);
                  },
                  style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
                  child: const Icon(Icons.fast_rewind),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FilledButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Wrap the play or pause in a call to `setState`. This ensures the
                    // correct icon is shown.
                    setState(() {
                      // If the video is playing, pause it.
                      if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                        _controller.pause();
                      } else {
                        // If the video is paused, play it.
                        _controller.play();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
                  child: Icon(_controller.value.isPlaying
                      ? Icons.pause
                      : Icons.play_arrow),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FilledButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Duration currentPosition = _controller.value.position;
                    Duration targetPosition =
                        currentPosition + const Duration(seconds: 10);
                    _controller.seekTo(targetPosition);
                  },
                  style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.brown[700],
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // Display the correct icon depending on the state of the player.
                  child: const Icon(Icons.fast_forward),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


When working with Stateful widgets if you want to access the variable within the state you need to prepend with "widget."
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';


class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String link;
  const VideoPlayerScreen({required this.link, super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerScreen> createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}


class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
  int pressCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
    // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
    // or the internet.
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(
       widget.link,
      ),
    );

    // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    // Use the controller to loop the video.
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.play();
  }

}

I have attached above the code to create a link variable within the stateful widget.
I recommend looking more into the documentation of stateful widgets: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html the documentation should help understand what you did wrong. For the record you were really close. You need to declare the variable you used like
final String link;
then use "widget.link" within the state to access it! This will make the widget reusable.

Thank you so much. I cant believe how close i was... Just the "widget." i missed. You are a life saver.

On a different note im also trying to put an asset video in like so and it not working...:
_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(
widget.link,
);
Any ideas??
Cheers

To get assets to work they need to be defined in the pubspec.yaml (Check this documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images )
Do like
assets:
- assets/videos/
The important part here is make a folder called assets in the root of your project. Same level as the lib folder. Then put a videos folder in it. Then any videos you want in that folder. Also please mark the answer as accepted :)

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it :)

I tried putting 2 on the screen and there is this massive gap? Any ideas what causes this? Full code of both files above https://i.sstatic.net/KKeBaEGy.png

You are using 2 expanded widgets. Expanded widgets try to take all remaining space. My guess is both expanded widgets are fighting for the space and therefore taking half the space each! Id start there
